flutter firebase background notification not working for iOS
I’m implementing Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in my Flutter app to handle push notifications. However, I’ve encountered the following issue:

Foreground: Notifications are received and processed successfully.
Background or Terminated: Notifications are not received, and I can’t handle them.

I have looked all of the other questions and answers but I couldn't solve my problem even I try everything
Versions

Flutter 3.24.5 • channel stable
Xcode Version 16.1 
firebase_messaging: ^15.1.6
flutter_local_notifications: ^18.0.1
IOS 18

main.dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");

  // Firebase'i başlatın

  // Burada bildirimi işleyebilirsiniz
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,  // Firebase config dosyasını doğru şekilde eklediğinizden emin olun.
  );
  NotificationSettings settings = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false, // Zorunlu bildirim yerine geçici izni aktive eder
      sound: true,
    );

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import flutter_local_notifications


@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
 override func application(
 _ application: UIApplication,
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
 ) -> Bool {
// This is required to make any communication available in the action isolate.
 FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
 GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
 }

 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
 }


 GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
 return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
 }

}

data
{
  "message": {
    "token": "",
    "data": {
      "receiver-id": "HBJq0SpqsrtoWjwIaH7kky14g4VZl53",
    },
    "notification": {
      "title": "Test Notification",
      "body": "This is a test message",
    },
    "apns": {
      "headers": {
        "apns-priority": "10"
      },
    "payload": {
        "aps": {
        "content-available": 1
        }
  }
    }
  }
}

info.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Snapstory</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>snapstory</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent...</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Image Picker</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Image Picker</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Image Picker</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Fotoğraf kütüphanesine fotoğraf kaydetmek için izin gerekiyor.</string>
    <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>dev.flutter.background.refresh</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

I try
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>

but not work
