Local notifications not coming in ios react native push notifications
I have added all the required code and permissions but not pushing local notification in ios working finr in android. Any one face this issue please help.
I have tried all the possible steps but not getting. please help to find the issue

Please share the code even if you have correctly set up all configurations. are you using notifiee?, try deleting pods, then reinstall pods pod install --repo-update

Please stop creating new accounts and asking the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79281718/flutter-firebase-background-notification-not-working-for-ios)[over] and over

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
